# Pass param to template event

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to pass a parameter to a template event? Something similar to the following:

HTML:

```
a(href="#"): i.mdi-action.delete-js(this._id, 'Organizations')
```

JS:

```
Template.application.events
   'click .delete-js': (id, collection)->
      Meteor.call 'deleteRecord', id, collection, (error, result) ->
         if error
            console.log "Error: application#delete-js: #{error.reason}"
         else
            window.history.back()
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not pretty sure if you can pass more params different to `function(event,template);`

did you already try something for example

```
Template.application.events({
'click .delete-js':function(event,template){
    Meteor.call('deleteRecord',this._id,function(error,result){
     if(!err){
        console.log("yea");
     }else{
       console.log(err.reason)
     }
   })
  }
})
```

And your meteor.method look like

```
Meteor.methods({
'deleteRecord':function(id){
   Posts.remove(id)
  }
})
```

maybe i don't get the question but you can pass the id into this and execute them into the event handler, remember that the `this` argument to the event handler is the data context of the element that triggered the event.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. So my main problem is knowing what collection I'm calling the delete for, because it could be any of the collections. So I need to pass that in to be able to call the correct one.

Comment: I think I'm just going to get it off of the current url and that will fix it. Thanks for you help on the other part.